# Parse xml file to data frame in python

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I hope you can help me.

I would like to get data from this XML file format.

```
<person id="10000115">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >25</attribute>
        <attribute name="carAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >never</attribute>
        <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >449528</attribute>
        <attribute name="employment" class="java.lang.String" >yes</attribute>
        <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.String" >1009431</attribute>
        <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >55</attribute>
            <attribute name="carAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >never</attribute>
            <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >450886</attribute>
            <attribute name="employment" class="java.lang.String" >yes</attribute>
            <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.String" >1023573</attribute>
            <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
        </attributes>
<person>
```

I have tried using this code

```
for person in root.iter('person'):
    #root1 = ET.Element('root')
    #print(person.attrib)
    root1 = person
    for attribute in root1.iter('attribute'):
        Id.append(person.attrib['id'])
        #Age = attribute.find('attribute').text
        Age = attribute.attrib.get('attributes')
```

But I failed to get the result.

The result that I expected is like this

```
id, age, carAvailibility, censusId, employment, htsId, sex
10000115, 25, never, 449528, yes,1009431,m
10000200, 55, never, 450886, yes, 1023573, m
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

xml = '''<person id="10000115">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >25</attribute>
        <attribute name="carAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >never</attribute>
        <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >449528</attribute>
        <attribute name="employment" class="java.lang.String" >yes</attribute>
        <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.String" >1009431</attribute>
        <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
    </attributes>
    <attributes>
            <attribute name="age" class="java.lang.Integer" >55</attribute>
            <attribute name="carAvailability" class="java.lang.String" >never</attribute>
            <attribute name="censusId" class="java.lang.Integer" >450886</attribute>
            <attribute name="employment" class="java.lang.String" >yes</attribute>
            <attribute name="htsId" class="java.lang.String" >1023573</attribute>
            <attribute name="sex" class="java.lang.String" >m</attribute>
        </attributes>
</person>'''

data = []

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
attrs = root.findall('.//attributes')
for attr in attrs:
    temp = {}
    for entry in list(attr):
        temp[entry.attrib['name']] = entry.text
    data.append(temp)
print(data)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
[{'age': '25', 'carAvailability': 'never', 'censusId': '449528', 'employment': 'yes', 'htsId': '1009431', 'sex': 'm'},
 {'age': '55', 'carAvailability': 'never', 'censusId': '450886', 'employment': 'yes', 'htsId': '1023573', 'sex': 'm'}]
  age carAvailability censusId employment    htsId sex
0  25           never   449528        yes  1009431   m
1  55           never   450886        yes  1023573   m
```